# Merge strategy for background NSManagedObjectContext saves

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a working app that downloads large files. Each file gets a corresponding NSManagedObject and its download progress is updated frequently via NSManagedObjectContext saves.

Initially I tried to avoid multiple threads for simplicity, but this was causing UI responsiveness issues, so I implemented a background thread for saving the progress updates. These are the only updates that are made in the background MOC.

Of course, now I have to merge changes between my background MOC and my main MOC. So I set up a notification listener to pick up the changes in both ways to keep each MOC in a valid state.

Here's where things begin to confuse me. I would expect this merging to be very simple. The changes to the model that either MOC handle are mutually exclusive (except, of course, for creating and deleting objects.) In other words, there should be no conflicts because no object will receive changes to the same property from both MOCs.

I've played with various merge policies for both MOCs and run into one of two problems. Either I get merge conflicts (which makes no sense to me, as explained above) or my changes aren't reflected in my UITableViews which use NSFetchedResultsControllers and were previously working fine. In the latter case, updates are reflected only when merges come in from the main and are merged into the background MOC (seemingly, anyway).

I hesitate to post my code because it's a bit of a mess right now and is proprietary anyway, but I'll do so if needed. First off, though, am I missing anything conceptually here? Which merge policy types make the most sense here? Should I need to merge both ways in this case, or should I be able to get by with a one way merge (background -> main)?

Comment: Background to main merge seems proper. You know what, consider using `RHManagedObject`. It's a relatively unknown yet well written, multithreaded library for Core Data. You'd have to refactor your code a little though.

Comment: I would recommend updating your object model on the background MOC and then applying the updates to the main-thread MOC.

Comment: @Bryan Isn't that what I'm doing?

Comment: You seemed to say you merge in both directions.

Comment: @Bryan I am merging in both directions. How is your suggestion different?

Comment: My suggestion is to merge in one direction, from background to main thread.  I guess I could have been clearer - where I said "applying the updates" I meant "merging the updates".

What I do is to create a new 'background' ManagedObjectContext for each set of updates, then use it, then throw it away after the updates are made.